# Filling this parabola with pattern

Tags: tikz-pgf, fillbetween

I'm not entirely familiar with tikz but I want to create a drawing of a parabola, shaded (with the pattern, north west lines) and bounded. So far I've got this:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\draw [->] (-3,0)--(3,0) node [right] {$x$};
\draw [->] (0,-1)--(0,6) node [below left] {$y$};

\draw [ultra thick, black] (0,0) parabola(2,5) node{$\bullet$};
\draw [densely dotted] (-2,5) -- (2,5);
\draw [ultra thick, black] (0,0) parabola(-2,5) node{$\bullet$};


\draw [pattern=north west lines] (0,0) parabola (2,5);

\draw (-0.5,-0.3) node {$(0,0)$};
\draw (0,0) node{$\bullet$};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: And well, thats not exactly what I'm looking for...]

And well, thats not exactly what I'm looking for as it leaves a lot of white space. If any suggestions could be made - I'm still fairly new and unexperienced, it would be much appreciated.

Comment: Welcome. // Can you please add a screenshot of your codes result to your question? (Unwanted white space etc.)

Answer (score 5):

You can use `parabola bend` to also place the parabola vertex. A char `\bullet` is not guaranteed to be centered and it will depend on the font, so I use `circle`.

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[->] (-3,0)--(3,0) node [right] {$x$};
\draw[->] (0,-1)--(0,6) node [below left] {$y$};
\draw[ultra thick, black] (-2,5) parabola bend (0,0) (2,5);
\fill (-2,5) circle[radius=2pt] (0,0) circle[radius=2pt] (2,5) circle[radius=2pt];
\draw[densely dotted, thick] (-2,5) -- (2,5);
\draw[pattern=north west lines]  (-2,5) parabola bend (0,0) (2,5);
\draw (-0.5,-0.3) node {$(0,0)$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Aparabola with filling]

Answer (score 3):

A small variation of @hpekristiansen answer (+1) with use `patterns.meta` library:

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=3.141592]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns.meta}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
dot/.style = {circle, fill, node contents={},
              inner sep=1.6pt, outer sep=0pt}
                        ]
% axis
\draw[->] (-3,0.0) -- (3,0) node [below left] {$x$};
\draw[->] (0,-0.5) -- (0,6) node [below left] {$y$};
% parabola 
\draw  [thick, 
        pattern={Lines[angle=45,distance={3pt},line width=0.2pt]},
                 pattern color=gray]
       (-2,5) parabola bend (0,0) (2,5);
\draw[densely dotted, semithick] 
    (-2,5) node[dot] -- (2,5) node[dot];
% coordinate origin
\path (0,0) node[below left] {(0,0)};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Edit:** removed superfluous nodes `dot` on parabola.

Comment: +1 I did not know `node[dot]` - I will try tor find it in the manual and read about it. Apparently it does not work with the parabola draw.

Comment: Ok - I first now I see that you define the `dot` yourself. Strange, that it does not work in the parabola draw.

Comment: @hpekristiansen, ups, Nodes `dot` should not be at parabola, but only at dashed line. Adding nodes to parabola make mess in drawings patterns. So i add them do  on the top of dashed area. I defined `dot` simple to make the code shorter and more transparent.

Comment: You have dots both in parabola and in dashed line. To make it work in the parabola, you need `fill=black` in the dot definition otherwise the pattern will be applied instead of fill.

Comment: @hpekristiansen, you are right. By mistake I forgot to delete `dot` on parabola (make some experiments, and after then apparently not clean-up final code). Thank you very much to spotted this.