# Adding another shaded region to this parabola

Tags: tikz-pgf

I asked a question yesterday, [Filling this parabola with pattern](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/648242/filling-this-parabola-with-pattern/648247#648247) to which was answered by the community and I have one more question to ask - how do I construct a small coloured/shaded strip in this parabola? Something that resembles:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

use `\clip`,as follows

```tex
\documentclass[tikz, border=3.141592]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns.meta}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
dot/.style = {circle, fill, node contents={},
              inner sep=1.6pt, outer sep=0pt}
                        ]
% axis
\draw[->] (-3,0.0) -- (3,0) node [below left] {$x$};
\draw[->] (0,-0.5) -- (0,6) node [below left] {$y$};
% parabola 
\draw  [thick, 
        pattern={Lines[angle=45,distance={3pt},line width=0.2pt]},
                 pattern color=gray]
       (-2,5) parabola bend (0,0) (2,5);
\draw[densely dotted, semithick] 
    (-2,5) node[dot]-- (2,5) node[dot];
% coordinate origin
\path (0,0) node[below left] {(0,0)};

\clip (-2,5) parabola bend (0,0) (2,5);
\draw  [red, 
        pattern={Lines[angle=60,distance={1.5pt},line width=0.2pt]},
                 pattern color=red] (0.5,0) rectangle (1.5,5);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

An approach using PGFplots (this is not based on the linked answer, but I think, drawing such diagrams is a bit easier using PGFplots, hence this alternative solution):

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns.meta}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        axis lines=middle,
        enlargelimits=0.25,
        ticks=none,
        xlabel=$x$,
        ylabel=$y$,
    ]
    
    \addplot[no markers, smooth, domain={-4:4}, name path=para, pattern={Lines[angle=45]}] {x^2};
    \addplot[mark=*, black, dashed, name path=line] coordinates {(-4,16) (4,16)};
    
    \addplot[red] fill between [of=para and line, soft clip={domain=1:3}];
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]